# Cannot sign in with credentials in next auth

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, prisma, vercel, next-auth

I'm new to `next-auth` and `prisma` and I was trying to build a website that combines them for authentication. In development mode the code works fine, however when I try to sign in with credentials from the deployed version it shows these errors in the console:

- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504()
- Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'A', "An error o"... is not valid JSON

I went to `Runtime Logs` in vercel and there I can see that `[POST]/api/auth/callback/credentials` went wrong. Here is my code `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/options.ts`

```
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

import prisma from '@/lib/prisma' 

export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "credentials",
      name: 'credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: 'Email',
          type: 'email',
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: 'password'
        }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email && !credentials?.password) {
          throw new Error("Please enter both fields")
        }

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email
          }
        });

        if (!user || !user?.hashedPassword) {
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials")
        };

        const isCorrectPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.hashedPassword
        )

        if (!isCorrectPassword) {
          throw new Error("Password is incorrect")
        };

        return user;
      }
    })
  ],
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  pages: {
    signIn: '/'
  },
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt'
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
}
```

`app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import { options } from "./options";

const handler = NextAuth(options);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

For the signin page I'm using a client component that imports `signIn` function from `next-auth/react`. Here is how it's called:

```
signIn("credentials", {
  email: 'random@email.com',
  password: 'random-password',
})
```

Comment: did you set env variable correctly on poduction?

Comment: Yes. I added the `NEXTAUTH_URL`, Prisma Database and Next Auth secret key

Comment: Your logs should provide a more detailed error. Can you please add it to your post?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the solution after 2 days. The problem wasn't with `next-auth`, it was with prisma. For some reason, even though I changed the build command on vercel so it runs `npx prisma generate && next build` it still didn't generate the prisma database. That's why I ran manually `npx prisma generate` and then redeployed my last commit from my remote github repository. After that it started working perfectly as intended.